# Users listed on answer deletion notice are not in the order of delete-vote time

Tags: support, review-queues, deleted-answers, post-notice

When a question is closed, the post notice always lists the users who voted to close in ascending order of the time of their close-vote. Also, if I'm not mistaken, the same happens when a question is deleted <sup>(can someone confirm?)</sup>.

However, I just noticed that when an *answer* is deleted by votes, the notice lists the users in seemingly random order.

For example, I reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368877/8967612) yesterday in the LQP queue, chose "Recommend deletion", and left a comment. Today, I saw that the answer is deleted but I noticed that the post notice shows my username at the end:

[image: Post notice on deleted answer]

Now, I know for a fact that the answer wasn't immediately deleted when I reviewed it yesterday (i.e., I wasn't the last reviewer). So, I went to double-check the dates in [the review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28892319) and found that I was, in fact, the *first* reviewer:

[image: Review item result]

**Why are the users shown on the post notice not listed in order?** Is this by design or is it a bug?

Comment: Most likely cross-site duplicate of [In which order are delete voters shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350142/289905) on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350149/348196) on Meta Stack Exchange before by [Spevacus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus).

#### Summary:

- It's not an "official" answer but the author has investigated this thoroughly and believes that they have a good level of confidence that they can provide enough examples to answer this properly, granted that they reviewed a fair number of Low Quality Posts.
- The order of displayed users depends on the outcome of the LQP review item. There are a few scenarios:

  > 1. Six recommend deletion votes successfully delete a post. These six users are displayed by order of their User ID.
  > 2. Three delete votes (or any number of delete votes and a ♦ moderator deletion) successfully deletes a post. The users who voted to delete are displayed chronologically.
  > 3. A mixture of recommend deletion votes and trusted user delete votes results in Recommended Deletion. All who contributed to this conclusion will be displayed in the post notice by order of their User ID.
  > 4. A mixture of recommend deletion votes and trusted user delete votes results in Trusted User deletion. Only trusted user's names will be displayed, and they are ordered chronologically.